# Converting Excel sheet of coordinates into multiple individual shapefiles

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, coordinates

I have a CSV file with coordinates in the CRS form and want to convert each set of coordinates into a standalone shapefile (ideally with QGIS software). So far, all instructions online seem to be directed at saving it into 1 giant shapefile.

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "each set of coordinates"? Do you want to save each record separately in a shapefile or grouped based on a value in a specific column?

Comment: Load your csv into qgis then run 'Split vector layer' from the processing toolbox. Note that each feature (row in your csv) needs to have a unique attribute value to split on for this to work. So if necessary, you should add a column to your csv before loading it  e.g. 'id' and fill it with sequential integers.

Comment: Does this really make sense? You really want in fact to have as many separate shapefiles (and layers, consequently) as you have features? Thus every single point is a separate file on its own? I'm not sure what you want to do, but I hardly can imagine a context/workflow where this makes sense. So you should reflect if there is a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @BenW thank you this worked very well

Comment: and @Babel you are right, was unfamiliar with how shapefiles worked... saved into 1 shapefile in the end thanks!